# How do I insert user_permissions field in user resource?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, tastypie

I have the following user resource code, how to insert the `'permissions field'` which returns the permission list for user?

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    user_permissions = fields.ToManyField #??????
    class Meta:
       queryset = User.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'user'
       authorization = Authorization()
       always_return_data = True
       list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
       authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
       authentication = MultiAuthentication(BasicAuthentication(), SessionAuthentication())
       filtering = {
           "date_joined": ALL,
           "email": ALL,
           "first_name": ALL,
           "is_active": ALL,
           "is_staff": ALL,
           "is_superuser": ALL,
           "last_login": ALL,
           "last_name": ALL,
           "username": ALL,
           "user_permissions": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using django-tastypie it could work like this without field.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
     class Meta:
         # your definitions

     def dehydrate(self, bundle):
         # Include user permissions
         bundle.data['user_permissions'] = bundle.obj.user_permissions()
         return bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
class PermissionResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Permission.objects.all()

        resource_name = 'permission'
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = True
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(BasicAuthentication(), SessionAuthentication())

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    user_permissions = fields.ToManyField(PermissionResource,'user_permissions',null=True,full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = True
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(BasicAuthentication(), SessionAuthentication())
        filtering = {
            "date_joined": ALL,
            "email": ALL,
            "first_name": ALL,
            "is_active": ALL,
            "is_staff": ALL,
            "is_superuser": ALL,
            "last_login": ALL,
            "last_name": ALL,
            "username": ALL,
            "user_permissions": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,

        }
```